# Why doesn't my Gnome applet appear in the list?

Tags: applet, pygtk, gnome

I'm trying to develop a Gnome applet. I use CentOS 6.5 (Gnome panel 2.30.2).

I've attempted to build a basic applet, copying from:

- https://github.com/benpicco/gnome-panel-python-applet-example
- https://github.com/nickcharlton/gnome-search-applet

I've done the following:

**Create a server file**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 myself mygroup ... /usr/lib/bonobo/servers/psleApplet.server
```

Code:

```
<oaf_info>
    <oaf_server iid="OAFIID:PsleApplet_Factory" type="exe" location="/usr/local/bin/psleApplet.py">
        <oaf_attribute name="repo_ids" type="stringv">
            <item value="IDL:Bonobo/GenericFactory:1.0"/>
            <item value="IDL:Bonobo/Unknown:1.0"/>
        </oaf_attribute>
        <oaf_attribute name="name" type="string" value="foo Factory"/>
        <oaf_attribute name="description" type="string" value="bar (factory)"/>
    </oaf_server>
    <oaf_server iid="OAFIID:PsleApplet" type="factory" location="OAFIID:PsleApplet_Factory">
        <oaf_attribute name="repo_ids" type="stringv">
            <item value="IDL:GNOME/Vertigo/PanelAppletShell:1.0"/>
            <item value="IDL:Bonobo/Controle:1.0"/>
            <item value="IDL:Bonobo/Unknown:1.0"/>
        </oaf_attribute>
        <oaf_attribute name="name" type="string" value="foo"/>
        <oaf_attribute name="description" type="string" value="bar"/>
        <oaf_attribute name="panel:category" type="string" value="Utility"/>
        <oaf_attribute name="panel:icon" type="string" value="gnome-applets.png"/>
    </oaf_server>
</oaf_info>
```

**Create a basic Python file**

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myself mygroup ... /usr/local/bin/psleApplet.py
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gtk
import pygtk
import gnomeapplet
pygtk.require('2.0')

def applet_factory(applet, iid):
    label = gtk.Label('It works!')
    applet.add(label)
    applet.show_all()
    print 'Factory started.'
    return True

if _name__ == '__main__':
    print "Sarting factory."
    gnomeapplet.bonnobo_factory('OAFIID:PsleApplet_Factory', gnomeapplet.Applet.__gtype__,'Sample Applet', '0.1', applet_factory)
```

**Additional information**

Here is my output when I run the Python file from the console:

```
>/usr/local/bin/psleApplet.py
Starting factory.
```

Note that the 'Factory started' message does not appear.

The referenced icon does exist:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root ... /usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-applets.png
```

---

So everything seems to be fine, but I can't find my applet in the list after a right click on a panel > Add to panel

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is likely the package - it isn't on pypy anymore, and [support appears to have been dropped](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=118401). It's likely much of the the package is littered with broken, legacy code.

Python support for Gnome applets has always been limited - you aren't going to find many posts regarding Python + gnome past 2011. Perhaps a better idea would be to create bindings via [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to the panel applet header ([panel-applet.h](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-panel/blob/master/libpanel-applet/panel-applet.h)). This would ensure you're getting working bindings (at least for Gnome 2.30.2) and would also give you a better understanding of gnome applets themselves.

EDIT: Bindings do already exist. Take a look at [PyGObject.](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)